# The soldier riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Soldiers carry their rations slung across their back;
>   I have no need for food, yet I too have a sack.
>   I do not stir; I remain silent and still;
>   Watching, waiting, to hear the enemy trill.
>   Then I strike, warding off the warriors of the air,
>   But soldiers of the ground, me they do not fear.
>   The vulnerable about me, it is my job to defend.
>   I fight day after day, but see no end.

What am I?

---

**Hint 1**:

> I am not an urban dweller.  I belong in the country.

**Hint 2**:

> When both Sides fight, my cousin's name is often invoked.

**Hint 3**:

> Portal 2 is the most evil computer game. I sympathise with GLaDOS.

**Hint 4**:

> The word "trill" is a big hint. Think about how this noun is typically used.

**Hint 5**:

> Fun fact: I am named after my enemy.

Comment: I'd say a rot13(fcvqre), except the last line and "no need for food" doesn't fit. Therefore, I'm just leaving it as a passing comment - if anybody can construe a proper fit, go for it.

Comment: Good attempt.  I agree - apart from those two lines, it is a great fit.  As a cryptic hint, your answer and the real answer would be allies against a common enemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have another guess:

> a Scarecrow.
>  Not sure about a couple of hints, but the rest seems to fit.

*Soldiers carry their rations slung across their back;
I have no need for food, yet I too have a sack.*

> A scarecrow doesn't need to eat, but usually wears a sack.

*I do not stir; I remain silent and still;
Watching, waiting, to hear the enemy trill.*

> A scarecrow remain immobile waiting for the birds.

*Then I strike, warding off the warriors of the air,
But soldiers of the ground, me they do not fear.*

> It scares the birds, but not other creature of the ground, like bugs.

*The vulnerable about me, it is my job to defend.
I fight day after day, but see no end.*

> It defends the vegetables in the field every day.

*I am not an urban dweller. I belong in the country.*

> Scarecrow are usually found in the countryside.

*Portal 2 is the most evil computer game. I sympathise with GLaDOS.*

> If i remember well in the game GLaDOS is kidnapped by a crow.

*The word "trill" is a big hint. Think about how this noun is typically used.*

> Trill is used to describe the sound produced by birds.

*Fun fact: I am named after my enemy.*

> scareCROW

I'm new to the site, I've already posted an answer, if I have to modify that one instead of adding another one I'll cancel this one.

Comment: Nicely done! That is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer with some explanations (loved the reference to Portal 2 and GLaDOS). Still can't get the second hint.

Comment: Perfect :) The connection to the second hint is rot13(Fvqrf, orvat gur Yrsg naq Evtug, jvyy bsgra hfr gur grez “fgenj zna” jura nethvat :))

Comment: ROT13(Nu, terng uvag! V'z abg n angvir Ratyvfu fcrnxre, V unq arire urneq gung rkcerffvba, gunaxf.)

Answer (score 2):

It could refer to

> Anti-aircraft system

*Soldiers carry their rations slung across their back;

I have no need for food, yet I too have a sack.*

> The sack in here could refer to the ammunition storage compartment of the defence system.

*I do not stir; I remain silent and still; 

Watching, waiting, to hear the enemy trill.*

> An anti-aircraft system waits still until it detects an enemy aircraft

*Then I strike, warding off the warriors of the air,

But soldiers of the ground, me they do not fear.*

> This defence system can take care of air-targets but can be targeted by attacks originating from the ground like tanks and rocket launchers.

*The vulnerable about me, it is my job to defend.

I fight day after day, but see no end.*

> The necessity of an aircraft defence system to guard a specific area can become its weakness as it is immobile and hence vulnerable to point-to-point missile attacks.

Comment: Good guess. I suppose it almost fits, if you take everything literally except the word "sack".  But the last two lines don't really fit. The "vulnerable about me" implies close proximity to them (which I think would be unlikely) and there would eventually be "an end".

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> a mosquito trap.

Not too sure about that, because

> "The vulnerable about me, it is my job to defend."
>  I don't think it fits this one very well, maybe it refers to humans?

Comment: Sorry, that is incorrect.

Comment: I've added some hints if you want to guess again.